# Select only the li item and not the ::marker, is it possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select the text part of a li and not the ::marker part.
So when I hover the li::marker the translation does not work but when I hover the text part, the translation works.

So I would like something like this but it doesn't work :

```
li:hover:not(li::marker) {
     transform: translate(20px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to reference in CSS. You could set `ul` to `list-style-type: none;` and create a custom `::marker` with a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and reference it that way.

However, with what it appears you're trying to do I think the following will work with a `span`.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
li:hover span {
  transform: translate(20px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>List item</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! However this is not exactly what I want, I want the ::marker to also translate when I hover the text part but I still don't want the translate when we hover the ::marker part.